# Why is my CSS file not working with my HTML page?

Tags: html, css

Why is my stylesheet not being applied? at first i had all my CSS in the same HTML file, then i created a CSS and copy pasted all my styles onto that file and linked it but now my styles aren't applying

I've already checked for syntax and the spelling is correct. also the html and css files are in the same folder so the path is good as well.

```
.google{
  display: block;
width: 200px;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.searchbox{
width: 590px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Search doppleganger</title>
    <link rel="styleheet" href="8c.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img   class="google" src="images-practice/google-logo-2.png">
    <input class="searchbox"
           type="search" 
           placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your browser agree that you provided the necessary path to the .css file?

Comment: It is a typo. **rel="styleheet"** should be **rel="stylesheet"**

Answer (score 1):

The line: `<link rel="styleheet" href="8c.css">` has "stylesheet" misspelled. It should be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="8c.css">`